# Preload fancybox image

Tags: fancybox-3

currently using fancybox 3.1

This is my website. http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/projects.html

How do i make the images load faster? How do i make the image load once user is in the page instead of when user click on the thumbnails

Currently it is on autoplay

```
<script>

                        $('[data-fancybox="project1"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true,
                        preload: '40',
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project2"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project3"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project4"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project5"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project6"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project7"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project8"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    $('[data-fancybox="project9"]').fancybox({
                        slideShow : {
                        autoStart : true
                                     },

                            });

                    </script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just google "preload images in javascript"

Comment: Hi Janis. I am using 3.1 and the autoplay is fine in all browsers except safari. In safari it only autoplays to 2nd image and then it stops

Answer (score 0):

For returning visitors you could set: "Cache-Control: max-age=31536000" (that's a year).
[Mozilla Developer Network on cache control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)